# Grammar of Mathematics

Tags: terminology

M and N are on the same side of P(1);
M and N are on same sides of P(2);
M and P are on the opposite side of N(3);
M and P are on opposite sides of N(4);
Which of the above is correct (grammar).
Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOYMV.png

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry, I added a image, I want ask what is the correct grammar to say it.

Comment: @Yuu, You can ask questions of this type in https://ell.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same side is one side, so singular.

Opposite sides are two distinct sides, so plural.

But the tag formal-grammar is for something very different.

Comment: Sorry, which tag should I add on this post?

Comment: @Yuu the terminology tag would be better suited.

Comment: Thank you for helping me.